# Mount a ubuntu portable machine as a hard drive on another ubuntu portable

Tags: boot, mount, hard-drive

For those that know Mac OS, I am looking for a way to replicate the Target mount mode in Ubuntu. Mac target mode is a startup mode that presents a firewire / usbc connected machine as a hard drive to another mac.
https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/transfer-files-mac-computers-target-disk-mode-mchlp1443/mac
It is extremely useful for copying data from one machine to another or for repairs.
I have a suspicion that Apple has this function in their "BIOS" but maybe it is in their core kernel.
Does this function exist in the linux world / Ubuntu by any chance?
Thanks